# Draw a path on a Google Map on one side only?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I'd like to replicate the outline effect shown on this map: https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&safe=off&q=switzerland&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x478c64ef6f596d61:0x5c56b5110fcb7b15,Switzerland&gl=uk&ei=PXO3UK3UPMS1hAfmjoDgBQ&sqi=2&ved=0CKQBELYD

In other words, I'd like to draw a path that:

- is shown along one side only of the path defined in GeoJSON
- fades in transparency from the outer side of the path to the inner?

Are either of these things possible with the Google Maps API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe to do this you would need to create a custom overlay - which can be a somewhat daunting task. See the documentation on [Custom Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) for a basic example.

Were I implementing this, I would create an overlay which used HTML5 canvas elements as tiles.